# Non linear results from output of timer qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

The following code is used as a 'GPS Simulator' inside of a much larger program. Thanks to help from the great people on this web site, I now have it working. However there is a small problem that I still need help with. GpsRunLoop (which generates gps coordinates) is triggered at a rate depending on the vaiable flyspeed. Flyspeed is created using a slider control in the ui. The slowest speed is around 20 mph using a flyspeed value of 120. Fastest speed is around 170 mph using a flyspeed value of 15. The 'small problem' is that the speed does not change in a linear fashion. When flyspeed is changed from 15 to 25, the speed changes from 170 mph to 85 mph. On the other end of the slider, when flyspeed is changed from 105 tp 115 the speed changes from 22 to 20.The speed change appears to be exponential. I would like to make this change occur in a linear fashion, but all of my attempts so far have failed. Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
double f,sk,ga,flat = 32.447414,flon = -100.131188, flat2, flon2, td;
int stp = 0,flyspeed = 67;
bool rungps;

void MainWindow::onGpsCalcLoop()
{
     //Get initial values from gps run loop-------
     double lat2 = flat2;
     double lat1 = flat;
     double lon2 = flon2;
     double lon1 = flon;
     //GPS distance and speed calculation -------
     double dLat = .01745329 * (lat2 - lat1);
     double dLon = .01745329 * (lon2 - lon1);
     lat1 = .01745329 * lat1;
     lat2 = .01745329 * lat2;
     double a = qSin(dLat/2) * qSin(dLat/2) +
         qSin(dLon/2) * qSin(dLon/2) * qCos(lat1) * qCos(lat2);
     double c = 2 * qAtan2(qSqrt(a), qSqrt(1-a));
     double d = 3975 * c;
     //Distance calculation done. Next is total distance and speed------
     td = td + d;
     if (d > .1)
     { 
         d = 0;
         td = 0;
     }
     if (ui -> metric -> isChecked())
     {
         ui -> valuetest1 -> setValue(td*1.6);
         ui -> valuetest2 -> setValue((d * 3600) * 1.6);
     }
     else
     {
         ui -> valuetest2 -> setValue(d * 3600);
         ui -> valuetest1 -> setValue(td);
     }
     flat2 = flat;
     flon2 = flon;
}
void MainWindow::onGpsRunLoop()
{
    QString la,lo,ll;
    flat = flat + .0000078;                // For north and south use .0000102 for 'flat', 0.0 for 'flon'
    flon = flon + .0000078;                // For east and west use .0000121 for 'flon', 0.0 for flat
    la = QString::number(flat, 'f', 6);    // For all 45 degree directions use .0000078 for both 'flat' and 'flon'
    lo = QString::number(flon, 'f', 6);
    ll = la + "," + lo;
    ui -> gps_latlon -> setText(ll);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
     ui -> pushButton_2 -> setChecked(0);
     rungps = true;
     gpscalcTimer->start(1000);
     gpsrunTimer->start(flyspeed);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
     ui -> pushButton -> setChecked(0);
     gpscalcTimer->stop();
     gpsrunTimer->stop();
     rungps = false;
}

void MainWindow::on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value)
{
    flyspeed = value;
    ui -> valuetest3 -> setValue(flyspeed);
    if(rungps)
    {
        gpsrunTimer->stop();
        gpsrunTimer->start(flyspeed);
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_metric_clicked()
{
    ui -> label_4 -> setText("kilometers");
    ui -> label_5 -> setText("kph");
}

void MainWindow::on_imperial_clicked()
{
    ui -> label_4 -> setText("miles");
    ui -> label_5 -> setText("mph");
}
```

The qt c++ project I use for testing can be downloaded at:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i8opg7a3jkzrmcv/AACuSfx9r9DDOXKO_DacT4nHa?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your `flyspeed` is actually an interval. So of course it behaves like that, it is an inverse relationship. If you multiply interval by *x*, the actual speed will be divided by *x*.

So basically, if you want to change increase speed from *v* to *v+d*, then you actually multiply speed by *((v+d)/v)*. So you need to adjust `flyspeed` by dividing with this.

However, what you actually want is to map the horizontal slider's speed value to interval for `flyspeed`, so something like this:

```
// map slider value so that speed 1 is interval 1000 ms, speed 100 is 10 ms
void MainWindow::on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value)
{
    if (value <= 0) {
        // speed is 0, stop timer, or something
        if(rungps) gpsrunTimer->stop();
    }
    else {
        double inverse = 1.0 / value;       //  100 -> 0.01,  speed 1 -> 1
        double interval = inverse * 1000; // 0.01 -> 10 ms,       1 -> 1000 ms
        flyspeed = interval; // implicitly truncating decimals
        ui->valuetest3->setValue(flyspeed);
        if(rungps)
        {
            gpsrunTimer->start(flyspeed);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that QTimer is not really accurate even to millisecond, and even if it were, that'd still be pretty inaccurate, so you need a different approach if you want accuracy... Still, check out [QTimer's timer type property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#timerType-prop), with right type it will *try* to achieve millisecond accuracy.

Comment: The accuracy of flyspeed is not important. It's only function is to update the GPS location at a variable/controlable rate. I would, however, like to be able to change flyspeed at a linear rate. Not being a math expert, I do not understand your formula. It appears to use the final speed value to feed back into the initial flyspeed value. I assume that the *= is a typo because I can't find any refeence to it as a math function. Also, I do not understand how to calculate a speed_delta.

Comment: `x *= y;` is same as `x = x * y;`, the standard *multiplication assigment operator*, which works in basically all programming langauges which have C-like basic syntax. `speed_delta` is change of speed actual speed you want. To have a different formula, you need to describe the relationship between speed and update interval (which you confusingly have named `flyspeed`).

Comment: @d_wheel I edited the answer a bit, I think this is what you are after?

Comment: For some reason, the variable inverse would not accept  of 1 / value. It always came up with 0. I added another variable, double xx = value. And then when I divided 1 / xx everything worked great!

Comment: @d_wheel Oops, yeah, standard integer/real promotion issue. I changed 1 to 1.0 in answer code as one way to force result of division to be a double float.